# Is there a way to get a query/stored procedure field and pass it to a form as an uneditable field, alongside other editable fields?

Tags: python, django, forms

## View:

```
def post(self, request):
    form = AnswerForm(request.POST) 
    if form.is_valid():
        post = form.save(commit=False)    
        post.save()
        messages.success(request, 'Thank you for your request')
        return redirect('consumer_answer')

    args = {'form':form} 
    return render(request, self.template_name, args)
```

## Form:

```
class AnswerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    question1 = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset = Question.objects.all())
    class Meta:
        model = Answer
        fields = ['answer', 'consumer']
```

## Template:

```
{% for answers in answer_request %}  
  <p>______________________________________________________________</p>

  <b><li> {{answers.5}}</li></b>
  <i><p> {{answers.6}}</p></i>
  Question ID: {{answers.8}}<br>

  <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{form.as_p}}
        <select id="question1">
          <option value= {{ answers.8 }}> Label </option>
        </select>
        <button type="submit">Submit Answer {{answers.8}}</button>
      </form>

{% endfor %}
</ol>
{% endif %}
```

At the moment, the above creates a blank form field called 'answer' (fine as this is completed by the user and then posts to db, but the next two fields of 'consumer' and 'question' are drop downs of all instances in the model). Would like the 'consumer' and 'question' field to be uneditable with the result of the query so they are then posted to the db. The query works fine outside of the form as the loop above the form successfully iterates and displays the output, I would just like to get it into the form. Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this myself with the following in view:

q = str(answer_request[1][0])
                form.fields["question"].queryset = Question.objects.filter(question_id = q)